# How to combine values of an object property into one based on a condition- Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
obj ={
  "AAA": 1,
  "BBB": 4,
  "CCC": 2,
  "DDD": 1,
  "EEE": 1,
  "FFF": 2,
  "AAA_TOTAL": 1,
  "BBB_TOTAL": 13,
  "GGG": 1,
  "HHH": 1,
  "III": 14,
  "JJJ": 35,
  "JJJ_TOTAL": 7,
  "KKK": 2,
  "LLL": 6,
  "MMM_TOTAL": 1,
  "OOO": 3,
  "PPP": 1
}
```

now I want to sum up the values of a property that includes TOTAL and has that property name included; Eg:

I want to sum up the values of AAA and similar property `AAA_TOTAL` => so the output would be :

```
obj["AAA"] + obj["AAA_TOTAL"]; => o/p would be  2
```

the TOTAL word can be attached to any property up there. example: it can also be: `GGG_TOTAL`
in this case, I want to sum up `GGG + GGG_TOTAL`

Other ex:

```
obj["BBB_TOTAL"] + obj["BBB"] => o/p would be 17
```

the final object should looks like:

```
obj2 ={
  "AAA": 2, (sum up value of "AAA_TOTAL": 1)
  "BBB": 17,( sum up value of "BBB_TOTAL": 13)
  "CCC": 2,
  "DDD": 1,
  "EEE": 1,
  "FFF": 2,
  "GGG": 1,
  "HHH": 1,
  "III": 14,
  "JJJ": 42,(sum of "JJJ_TOTAL": 7)
  "KKK": 2,
  "LLL": 6,
  "MMM": 1, (just removing the TOTAL string here and reatining the value as no "MMM" is present to sum)
  "OOO": 3,
  "PPP": 1
}
```

this is not a static list of properties and is subject to change, hence I cannot use a hard coded condition.

code:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    op={}; 
    id = key.replace(/_total$/gi,'');
    op[id] = op[id] || 0;
    op[id] += value; 
    console.log(op)
}
```

this does not give me desired o/p: it gives this which I'm not looking for:

```
obj ={
  "AAA": 1,
  "BBB": 4,
  "CCC": 2,
  "DDD": 1,
  "EEE": 1,
  "FFF": 2,
  "AAA": 1,
  "BBB": 13,
  "GGG": 1,
  "HHH": 1,
  "III": 14,
  "JJJ": 35,
  "JJJ": 7,
  "KKK": 2,
  "LLL": 6,
  "MMM": 1,
  "OOO": 3,
  "PPP": 1
}
```

this just removes the "TOTAL" string from property but does not remove that property itself and does not sum.

any help??

Comment: You're emptying `op` every time through the loop. This is the common beginner mistake that I never understand. Iniitialize it once before the loop.

Comment: Fix that and it should work.

Comment: I don't see how your code is producing the result you show. It should just be an object with the last property.

Comment: thnank @Barmar: super rookie mistake:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const newObj = Object.keys(obj2).reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (key.indexOf('_TOTAL') === -1) {
      acc[key] = obj2[key] + (obj2[`${key}_TOTAL`] || 0);
    }
    return acc;
  }, {}),
```